# Safari Browser Detection to Change CSS Behavior - Display Flex/Block

Tags: css, flexbox, safari

I'm not very good with coding or CSS so I need some help.  What i'm trying to do I feel should be simple but it's seemingly not for me.  I got some code knocked up (CGPT) and it was working fine until the latest version of Safari came out v16.5.

What I want to do is;

When a Safari Browser is detected to change the CSS style to 'display: block' for an object on my webpage.  The reason for this is because the 'flex' condition simply doesn't work properly on Safari that I've read (and seen).

I want it to remain as 'flex' for all other browsers.  The behaviour can be observed here after a search is executed on Safari (everything is squashed up after a search);

[www.bestcarhire.com/test/](http://www.bestcarhire.com/test/)

The code is this;

```
/* Styles for the 'webtest' ID in non-Opera and non-Safari browsers */
#webtest {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /* Additional styles */
}

/* Exclude display: flex; for Opera and Safari */
@media not all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) and (min-resolution:.001dpcm),
       not all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
  #webtest {
    display: block;
    /* Additional styles for Opera and Safari */
  }
}
```

If someone has any ideas or alternatives let me know.  I tried a few Java / PHP alternatives too but no luck.  It behaves as though it's not detected Safari and runs in flex.  25$ Paypal if someone has a solution!

Cheers

---

Comment: Ugh, browser detection. Avoid that like the plague. Flex works fine in Safari. I tried your form. It worked fine in Safari, but kept throwing a red, meaningless error in Chrome: "Alternating your pick-up and drop-off times". Frustrating.

Comment: Hmm really?  This is what I see;

https://i.ibb.co/31x09JB/Image-24-05-23-at-5-01-PM.jpg

The alternating days thing happens if you've selected a time that's in the past.  Cheers!

Comment: Do you have a reference for where you've read that there is a problem with Safari 16.5? I haven't seen anything.

Comment: I haven't read anything. Yesterday the Safari version on my Mac Air was 15.xx, today it updated to 16.5 and now the exact same CSS doesn't seem to work for me.  Although it appears to work for Ralph, I don't know what version he's on.  I'm assuming it's the update as that's all that's changed.

Comment: I am not seeing any problem on Safari/IOS 16.5 (iPad).

Comment: I was using Safari 16.4, Ventura, MacBook.

Comment: Thanks all, then I'm baffled. Maybe it's because my Mac Air is around 7 years old now. Weird.

Comment: @amdaman was anything changed to your test site since you first posted this issue?  I too am running into display problems with d3 charts rendered as svg  with `display:-webkit-box` after updating to 16.5.  If I change to `display:flex`, it displays fine.  Trying your test site looks fine even on 16.5.1 safari.

Comment: @sonyisda1 - I left the code alone after users reported it was displaying fine.  It's still ropey on my old mac air but everyone else seems to be ok.  Cheers